# OneDrive syncing SharePoint sites: Remove redundant " - Documents" suffix from folder names

Tags: sharepoint-online, folder, sync, onedrive, synchronisation

If you have a SharePoint site called:

- **My Site Name**

...and sync its "Documents" to your computer with OneDrive, it always calls the local folder:

- **My Site Name - Documents**

The " - Documents" suffix is completely redundant, and just creates visual clutter that annoys users.  Especially when they're syncing many sites.

Is there any way to remove this and simply have it name the local folders with the site name alone:

- **My Site Name**

This is a new tenant, so nobody is syncing anything yet.  So I don't need to make changes for users who are already syncing.  I just want to get this figured out before setting anything up.

Answer (score 0):

This is by design and we cannot change it.

If we try to rename it within explorer, the following error will appear:

[image]